# How to use JSOn response in different clases swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using `swifty.JSON` for parsing `JSON`, and i got the expected out put in

```
var outPut = JSON(data: data!)
```

but I would like to declare this `outPut` `variable` as `global` inorder to return this as return value for a function. Because I want to use this JSON response in someother class. how to get this??

Answer (score 0):

Get `AppDelegate` `object` like this :

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

Now add `var jsonData` `object` to `AppDelegate`. `Set` data to this object like this:

```
appDelegate.jsonData = outPut;
```

Comment: thanks for quik replay.. I would like to do this by return value of my function

Comment: func executePostRequest(url: String, data:NSDictionary)
{                                                               var outPut = JSON(data: data!)   I want to use this outPut as my return value}

Answer (score 0):

@prince is right, but if you want a function instead, you could try something like this:

```
// I'm declaring the return type as `JSON` since I think it's what SwiftyJSON creates. 
// I also make it an Optional since it can be nil.
func getJSONFromRequest(data: NSDictionary?) -> JSON? { 
    if let myData = data, let result = JSON(data: myData) {
        return result
    }
    return nil
}

let myJSON = getJSONFromRequest(data: myDataFromNetwork)
```

It's just an example, you should adapt it to your specific case.